# QGIS2web label doesn't want to come out

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, javascript, qgis2web

I would like to have label visible for both cryterias in my layer.

One case works fine whereas the other one doesn't.

In the code everything is exactly the same...

```
    function categories_Area5chamber_14(feature, value, size, resolution, labelText,
                   labelFont, labelFill, bufferColor, bufferWidth,
                   placement) {
            switch(value.toString()) {case 'BT':
                return [ new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'rgba(35,35,35,1.0)', lineDash: null, lineCap: 'butt', 
    lineJoin: 'miter', width: 0}),fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1.0)'}),
    text: createTextStyle(feature, resolution, labelText, labelFont,
                          labelFill, placement, bufferColor,
                          bufferWidth)
    })];
                break;
    case 'Voneus':
                return [ new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'rgba(35,35,35,1.0)', lineDash: null, lineCap: 'butt', 
    lineJoin: 'miter', width: 0}),fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(252,0,0,1.0)'}),
    text: createTextStyle(feature, resolution, labelText, labelFont,
                          labelFill, placement, bufferColor,
                          bufferWidth)
    })];
                break;}};
```

the `createTextStyle` function looks exactly the same!

Next in the styling:

```
  var style_Area5chamber_14 = function(feature, resolution){
  var context = {
    feature: feature,
    variables: {}
};
var value = feature.get("Chamber Type");
var labelText = "";
size = 0;
var labelFont = "15px \'MS Shell Dlg 2\', sans-serif";
var labelFill = "#787878";
var bufferColor = "";
var bufferWidth = 0;
var textAlign = "center";
var offsetX = 0;
var offsetY = 0;
 var placement = 'point';
  if (feature.get("Chamber No") !== null) {
    labelText = String(feature.get("Chamber No")); labelFont = "15px \'MS Shell Dlg 2\', sans-serif";
 }
  var style = categories_Area5chamber_14(feature, value, size, resolution, labelText,
                      labelFont, labelFill, bufferColor,
                      bufferWidth, placement);          
   return style;
```

I have got all the variables defined, which unfortunately are displayed with one case only. How about the other case?

For this occasion I'vee made the alterations:

```
  else if (feature.get("X") !== null) {
    labelText = String(feature.get("X")); labelFont = "15px \'MS Shell Dlg 2\', sans-serif";
  }
```

but still without the result...

Does anyone know how to solve it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main reason behind it is our **map zoom**.
Basically, the QGIS2web plugin gives us the zoom range between 1 and 28. Sometimes, we don't want as big zoom as 28, and we can set it smaller like 21 or 22. In this event, when our string is long enough, it won't be displayed.

In order to check it (alternatively), we can use the `substring` property and define how many elements of our string we want to have visible.

```
   if (feature.get("Chamber No") !== null) {
    labelText = String(feature.get("Chamber No")).substring(0,6);
    }
```

When our string is too long for i.e. zoom level 22, we have to make it shorter then entering our later file and making relevant changes.